# JavaScript if-statement with AND and dates

Tags: javascript

I have a statement like this:

```js
// this is a date I select from input field and set its time to 12AM
var date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
console.log(date);
var currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate);

if (date.getTime() === new Date(currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() && currentDate.getTime() > (new Date(currentDate.setHours(11,30,0,0)).getTime())) {
            console.log("It works!!!");
}
else{
console.log("That didn't work as expected :(");
}
```

And I don't know why it is not working. when I check each comparison in IF statement separately it works but with && it's not.

What can be a problem here?

Comment: The second check `currentDate.getTime() > (new Date(currentDate.setHours(11,30,0,0)).getTime())` returns to `false`. That's why it returns to "That didn't work as expected :(". What are you trying to check there?

Comment: I'm selecting date from input field in form (var date) and need to check if it's today if yes then I need to check if it's already past 11:30 and prevent from submitting form for this date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At last, after some interesting debugging, I managed to find your issue.**

The line,

**`date.getTime() === new Date(currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime()`** in your first condition **is changing the currentDate variable** you have taken above, using the code `currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`, which is making the second conition to fail.

So, if you take them both it is not working,

Here is an example of the **not working** snippet.

```js
var date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
console.log(date);
var currentDate = new Date();

if(date.getTime() === new Date(currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() && currentDate.getTime() > (new Date(currentDate.setHours(11,30,0,0)).getTime())) {
    console.log("It works!!!");
}
else{
 console.log("That didn't work as expected :(");
}
```

Now, check the **working snippet**

```js
    // this is a date I select from input field and set its time to 12AM
    var date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    console.log(date);
    var currentDate = new Date();
    
    if(date.getTime() === new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() && currentDate.getTime() > (new Date(currentDate.setHours(11,30,0,0)).getTime())) {
    
                console.log("It works!!!");
    }
    else{
      console.log("That didn't work as expected :(");
    }
```

I have taken,

`new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime()` **instead of**

`currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime()` so that, `currentDate` is not modified in the first condition.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you

Comment: @PiotrSmyda, Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
console.log(date);
var currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate);

if (date.getTime() === new Date(currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() && currentDate.getTime() > (new Date(currentDate.setHours(11,30,0,0)).getTime())) {
            console.log("It works!!!");
}
else{
console.log("That didn't work as expected :(");
}

console.log(date.getTime() === new Date(currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime());

console.log(currentDate.getTime() > (new Date(currentDate.setHours(11,30,0,0)).getTime()));
```

That`s why, "That didn't work as expected :("

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
var date = new Date();
var today1130 = new Date(new Date().setHours(11,30));

console.log("input date is today: ", date.toDateString() === today1130.toDateString());
console.log("input date is after today 11:30: ", date > today1130);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it didn't work is because there's a miscalculates for times between 11:30am and 12:00pm. Try this and let me know :)

```
var todaysNoon = new Date();
var nextNoon = new Date();

todaysNoon.setHours(11,30,0,0);
if (todaysNoon <= nextNoon){ nextNoon.setDate(nextNoon.getDate()+1); }
nextNoon.setHours(11,30,0,0);

if (todaysNoon.getTime() <= new Date(nextNoon.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() && todaysNoon.getTime() <= new Date(nextNoon.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime()) {
    console.log("It works!!!");
} else {
    console.log("That didn't work as expected :(");
}
```

Hope this helps.